# How can I change default backup location for oracle11g using RMAn?

Tags: oracle11g, database-backups, rman

I want to change to another drive due to lack of disk space.

How can I change the default location of backup files used by oracle to another drive using RMAN?

By default it's in the folder `ORACLE_HOME` from variables.

edit:

Found some links with problems like mine [here](http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1631901-wrong-rman-backup-location-configure.html), but they didn't help.

My script looks like this one:

`run {

allocate channel d1 type disk;

allocate channel d2 type disk;

backup

format 'd:/backups/%U.bkp'

database plus archivelog;

release channel d1;

release channel d2;

}`

Edit : By running the above scripts the backup will never finish

Comment: This is a DBA question, not a programming one.

Comment: You can't - enough people with reputation can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performing a `BACKUP` operation with `RMAN`, the location of backupsets / backup pieces / image copies / etc is determined by the `ALLOCATE CHANNEL` command.

```
run 
{
  allocate channel d1 device type disk format 'd:/backups/%U.bkp';
  backup database include current controlfile;
  release channel d1;
}
```

If not specifying a location for a disk channel, Oracle defaults the location to $ORACLE_HOME, as that's a path Oracle knows exists.

Comment: Why do we need -                                                      
    `backup database include current controlfile;
    release channel d1;' ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Oracle RMAN you can now back up to Cloud/Amazon S3, check this out:

["Using Oracle Database with Amazon Web Services"](http://www.slideshare.net/guest484c12/using-oracle-database-with-amazon-web-services)